# How can I change some text in an ActionBar item after an onOptionItemSelected event?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionBar in my application, and I want when the user clicks a button, the item in the ActionBar should change the text.

This is my code for `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.lg:

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ma", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.French:

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "zaki", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        break;
    case R.id.nerlandais:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "brahim", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

    return true;
}
```

What must I do to change the item title from another item?

Example: **When I click in French item I want to change nerlandais item title.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change an `MenuItem`'s title clicking to another item you can do something like this :

private String mMenuItemTitle;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.nerlandais);
    item.setText(mMenuItemTitle);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.French:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "zaki", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMenuItemTitle = "My New Title";
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        break;
    }

return true;
```

}

Comment: hy android developer how can i get the menu in this line i haven't in my code menu variable

Comment: hy i did your code and it goes good but i haven't supportinvaidateoptionmenu, android change to invalidateOptionsMenu(); and the menu change place from right to left i didn't know why , there is another metode to refresh android action bar

Comment: `invalidateOptionsMenu()` is if you are using ActionBar , `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` is for ActionBarSherlock and as far as I know these are the only functions which are used to invalidate / refresh actionbar items.

Comment: thank you android developper i used your code to do what i would bu without refreshing actionbar i just serach id and change the title , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [item.setTitle("new title")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Or, if from another item then the Menu has [findItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem%28int%29)

Comment: hy alex i have like this menu                                language                                                                         french                                                              english                                                          when i click in languge item i have 2 other item french and english. what i want is when i choose french the languge item change title to french. for your 2 proposition how can i have the menu in java code.